# Creating ATM with while loop

Tags: java

I have for school a project to create a ATM. I have done everything, the only problem is when the user doesn't type the same pin again to verify, the program still thinks the pin is good.

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ValidatePin {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a new pin between 1 and 9");
        double number = keyboardInput.nextInt();

        while (number == keyboardInput.nextInt()) {
            if (number > 0 && number < 10000) {

            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Error, this pin is not able to use");
            }

            if (number == number) {
                System.out.println("Your pin is verified!");
            }

            if (number != keyboardInput.nextInt()) {
                System.out.println("Error, this pin is not the same!");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in which circumstances do you ever think this will return false ?  if (number == number) {

Comment: If the user doesn't enter the same pin again, the program is supposed to print out an error

Comment: I understand that part, but you really should check. what you are doing is: if  (true ) print "verified";. Seeing as true will always be true, that will always print, but still, you'll be expected to enter a pin after that print

Comment: So how do I make it that it not always will be able to print out true?

Comment: The program gives the next output: Enter a pin between 1-9. Example: 1234 4321, Build successful. The program should give the next output:  Enter a pin between 1-9. Example: 1234 4321, Error

Comment: What exactly do you want it to be compared to?

Comment: The program requires a while loop

Comment: @StijnvanWoerkom What about changing the while condition and do it while the required number isn't between 1 and 9 or whatever are your requirements, in that case ask for a new number

Comment: @Stijn at this point, having to use a while loop or not is irrelevant to what is going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to keep pin as four digits instead 1 to 10000. While loop run until user provides the correct pin for the second time.

```
    Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a new pin between 1000 and 10000");
    double number1 = keyboardInput.nextInt();
    double number2 = 0;
    boolean bool=true;
    while (bool) {
    number2 = keyboardInput.nextInt();      
    if (number2> 1000 && number2 < 10000) {
         if(number1 == number2){                  
         System.out.println("Your pin is verified!"); 
         bool=false;
         }
         else{
          System.out.println("Please Re-enter the same pin");   
         }  
    }
    else{
    System.out.println("Pin should be between 1000 and 10000"); 
    }
 }
```

Comment: what if the pin is 0000

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear why you are using a `while` loop. Try below code and see whether this is what you want.

Note that I have used `int` for `number1` and `number2`. No point in using `double` to store integer values.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ValidatePin {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
      System.out.println("\nEnter a new pin between 1 and 9999");
      int number1 = keyboardInput.nextInt();
      if (number1 > 0 && number1 < 10000) {
        System.out.println("Enter the same pin again");
        int number2 = keyboardInput.nextInt();
        if (number1 == number2) {
          System.out.println("Your pin is verified!");
          break;
        }
        else {
          System.out.println("Error, this pin is not the same!");
        }
      }
      else {
        System.out.println("Error, this pin is not able to use");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I need to use a while loop in my school project.

Comment: @StijnvanWoerkom, ok. I have added a `while` loop to my answer now. It loops till user enters a correct pin.